# SQL Join Issue - msg 4145

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following code:

```
 SELECT *
 From [CMM].[dbo].[schedule] S
   join [CMM].[dbo].[schedule_activity] SA 
        ON S.[schedule_id = SA.schedule_id
   join [CMM].[dbo].[schedule_activity_part] SAP 
    ON SA.schedule_activity_id = SAP.schedule_activity_id
   join [CMM].[dbo].[activity] A 
    ON SA.activity_id = A.activity_id
 Where S.schedule_id = '5106'
```

And I am getting this error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'SAP'.

Comment: is it because you're missing a bracket?

Comment: You might want to add some [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_sugar) and specitfy the joins as `INNER JOIN`instead of just `Join`. Won't make any difference, but it's arguably easier to read.

Comment: it is a very simple syntax issue (missing close bracket on `S.[schedule_id` <---

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you missed a bracket in your query. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fourth row is wrong or at least has a typo:
 `ON S.[schedule_id = SA.schedule_id`
There's an `[` too much

Comment: or a `]` too little...

Comment: Indeed. I can't really see any reason for the brackets in this query at all though, the identifiers doesn't seem to require bracketing.

Comment: agreed, die brackets die!